# Place a condition on a for loop in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the for loop below and I am trying to place a condition for it:

```
: FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${size}
\    Validate Item List    ${items[${i}]}
```

so that the for runs only if the condition is met.
I tried "Run keyword if", but that does not seem to work:

```
Run keyword if    ${flag}>0    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${size}
...    \    Validate Item List    ${items[${i}]}
```

I get "No keyword with name ': FOR' found.".

Note: flag can be zero or negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Run Keyword If' keyword cannot be used directly for "For-Loop".

For-loop statements should be mentioned inside an user defined keyword and then 'Run Keyword If' should be mentioned as below:

```
 User Defined function for For Loop
    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${size}
    \    Validate Item List    ${items[${i}]}


 Run Keyword If   ${flag}>0   User Defined function for For Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

From code perspective I can imagine two ways of doing the same:

```
${size} =    Run Keyword If    "${flag}">"0"    Get Size    #Whatever you want here
...    ELSE    Set Variable    0    #0 in order to make the loop not looping at all
: FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${size}
\    Validate Item List    ${items[${i}]}
```

Or alternatively you can do following:

```
: FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${size}
\    Exit For Loop If    "${flag}">"0"
\    Validate Item List    ${items[${i}]}
```